# How to get iTunes to skip over 1 star songs?

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to get iTunes to just never play any 1 star songs. I know I can delete the 1 star songs but just wondering if there is a way to just skip them.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to do this is to make a Smart Playlist with the rule of "Rating is not 1 star". The playlist will auto-update as you add and rate new music. You would just want to make sure you always play your songs from this smart playlist or make other playlists include the "white list" or exclude a "black list" that consists of all one star items.